# java 11 gc log path in Windows change file separator

Tags: java-11, adoptopenjdk

Java AdoptOpen 11.0.13

I'm running the following java command in a Windows Server 2016 operating system:

```
java -Xlog:gc*:file="C:\users\test_gc.log" -version
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
java -Xlog:gc*:file="C:/users/test_gc.log" -version
```

But this fails. In java 8, however, this was acceptable, and the quotes weren't required due to its xloggc syntax.

**Is there a way to tell java 11 which file separator to use?**

The loss of a universal forward slash in my paths has been wreaking havoc with running software in windows that has multiple embedded 3rd-party java components, as each embedded component parses the backslashes differently. Right now I have a combination of single backslashes, double backslashes, and even 4 backslashes as path separators for different java components. Two components even crash due to the quotes, although somehow they start up fine without any quotes.